# Unknown error in Salesforce Production Org. Is this a bug in Salesforce?

Tags: bug

Suddenly this error came and displayed on the left panel. Why is this happening in Production org? Is this a Salesforce bug? Somebody in the Salesforce testing their usecases? Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any Salesforce related chrome extension installed?

Comment: I have grammarly and true key installed. How is it related with this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is reported as Known Bug on salesforce due to beta app named 'Dev Hub'. Please look at the following link.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001ChdQAE&title=summer-17-missing-label-for-beta-app-dev-hub-in-app-menuz

Currently there is no workaround for that. This is a cosmetic unexpected behavior that only appears in the Setup menu. No functionality is broken as a result